# Paste columns in separate file with save() in R

Tags: r, file, save, concatenation, paste

I am using a for loop to impute values per column, and want to save these columns with the predictions to another file. So, that the columns are pasted in there one by one. However, my code throws an error and it is not working. This is the part of the code:

```
for (column in 1:ncol(NB_mcar)) {

# Imputing values for all columns ---------------------------------------------------------
NBpredictions <- predict(NBmodel, NBtest)

# Saving predictions into file ------------------------------------------------------------
save(NBpredictions, paste("NB_predictions_", column, ".csv"))

# Retrieving the true values that we thought were missing ---------------------------------
NBtrue <- subset_IPUMS[is.na(NB_mcar[, column]), column]

}
```

What am I doing wrong? Does the 'NB_predictions_.csv' already have to exist?

Btw, I get the following error:

```
Error in save(NBpredictions, paste("NB_predictions_", column, ".csv")) : 
object ‘paste("NB_predictions_", column, ".csv")’ not found`
```

Comment: Have you tried using `write.csv()` instead of `save()`? Anyway, your problem probably stems from disregarding the value sequence of `save`: The second item is not `file`, so, as @Elin says, you need to specify.

Comment: You have to put `file=`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the function [`write.csv`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.4.3/topics/write.table). In the [documentation of save](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/save.html) it states that the unnamed arguments `...` are

> "the names of the objects to be saved (as symbols or character
>   strings)"

So rather than saving your dataframe to csv, you are trying to save the object called `paste("NB_predictions_", column, ".csv")`, which does not exist.

Comment: Yes if you just save() it is saving the data frame object, so you should really make the extension be `Rda` or similar to avoid confusion.  If you want to save to a csv file you need to do what @Florian says and use the correct function for that.